# how can i list the contents of a mega public folder by it's shared url using mega api in python

Tags: python, python-3.6

i want to iterate over a public folder contents using it's shared link in python and to extract it's information using mega api
the only available method is for getting the files list that only available in a specific account only

```
 def get_files_in_node(self, target):
    """
    Get all files in a given target, e.g. 4=trash
    """
    if type(target) == int:
        # convert special nodes (e.g. trash)
        node_id = self.get_node_by_type(target)
    else:
        node_id = [target]

    files = self._api_request({'a': 'f', 'c': 1})
    files_dict = {}
    shared_keys = {}
    self._init_shared_keys(files, shared_keys)
    for file in files['f']:
        processed_file = self._process_file(file, shared_keys)
        if processed_file['a'] and processed_file['p'] == node_id[0]:
            files_dict[file['h']] = processed_file
    return files_dict
```

can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Retrieving a list of nodes from a public folder's URL

Here is the code that I used to get the list of files in Mega's public folder. It uses functions related to decryptions from [mega.py](https://github.com/odwyersoftware/mega.py) library.

```py
from mega.crypto import base64_to_a32, base64_url_decode, decrypt_attr, decrypt_key

def get_nodes_in_shared_folder(root_folder: str) -> dict:
    data = [{"a": "f", "c": 1, "ca": 1, "r": 1}]
    response = requests.post(
        "https://g.api.mega.co.nz/cs",
        params={'id': 0,  # self.sequence_num
                'n': root_folder},
        data=json.dumps(data)
    )
    json_resp = response.json()
    return json_resp[0]["f"]

def parse_folder_url(url: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    "Returns (public_handle, key) if valid. If not returns None."
    REGEXP1 = re.compile(r"mega.[^/]+/folder/([0-z-_]+)#([0-z-_]+)(?:/folder/([0-z-_]+))*")
    REGEXP2 = re.compile(r"mega.[^/]+/#F!([0-z-_]+)[!#]([0-z-_]+)(?:/folder/([0-z-_]+))*")
    m = re.search(REGEXP1, url)
    if not m:
        m = re.search(REGEXP2, url)
    if not m:
        print("Not a valid URL")
        return None
    root_folder = m.group(1)
    key = m.group(2)
    # You may want to use m.groups()[-1]
    # to get the id of the subfolder
    return (root_folder, key)

def decrypt_node_key(key_str: str, shared_key: str) -> Tuple[int, ...]:
    encrypted_key = base64_to_a32(key_str.split(":")[1])
    return decrypt_key(encrypted_key, shared_key)
```

Example code to get a list of files and their metadata in the public shared folder.

```py
(root_folder, shared_enc_key) = parse_folder_url("<insert url here>")
shared_key = base64_to_a32(shared_enc_key)
nodes = get_nodes_in_shared_folder(root_folder)
for node in nodes:
    key = decrypt_node_key(node["k"], shared_key)
    if node["t"] == 0: # Is a file
        k = (key[0] ^ key[4], key[1] ^ key[5], key[2] ^ key[6], key[3] ^ key[7])
    elif node["t"] == 1: # Is a folder
        k = key
    attrs = decrypt_attr(base64_url_decode(node["a"]), k)
    file_name = attrs["n"]
    file_id = node["h"]
```

## Downloading files from shared folder

This wasn't part of your question, but I'll just add a brief summary and maybe others will find it helpful.

To download, you will need to make a POST request with the same params as above but the data changed to this:

```py
data = [{ 'a': 'g', 'g': 1, 'n': node['h'] }]
```

and then basically copy the mega.py library's `_download_file` function, replacing `file_key` with the key you got from `decrypt_node_key(...)`.

Comment: I've got a json from mega successfully, but had a list, so return json_resp[0]["f"] worked for me.      But then there is a problem in  line  
attrs = decrypt_attr(base64_url_decode(node["a"]), k) 
 => mega\crypto.py line 92, in a32_to_str => return struct.pack('>%dI' % len(a), *a)
 - it says "struct.error: required argument is not an integer". Don't really get, what am idoing wrong.   
This is the first elemnts ['k']: 'el1DVYzb:O2Cl8oAIQegmd53UoSQrhg'

Comment: Sory, made a mistake - the problem is with line:        
key = decrypt_node_key(node["k"], shared_key)

Comment: @AntonMakarov Fixed the code! I forgot to decode the shared key.

Comment: Ok, nice. Now i see the right names of my files.  But what about downloading? Why simply putting handle and decrypted_file_key into _download_file is not enough to download? Why do we need a POST request?

Comment: I created a _download_file_NEW method, gave file_data from our last response...  But still it crashes on the last line, trying to move temporary file to my dest_path (shutil.move(temp_output_file.name, output_path).   I suppose, the temp file has not downloaded yet, when it's trying to move... It says, file is used by another process.  Any ideas?

Comment: I did it. Thank you!  There is a wrong indent of the last block in "_download_file" method. It tries to move a file before it is downloaded and released by a tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile context manager. It's better to put it otside of the CM.

Comment: sorry, i stopped working on that because i gave up, searching for a solution but thanks, it worked for me

Comment: I have a question about the function "parse_folder_url": I always get the top folder of the "share", regardless of the link I provide. I think this is what you tried to explain in the comment inside the function, but changing the root_folder line to "root_folder = m.groups()[-1]" didn't work

Comment: @Rom Try getting nodes in the root folder, but among the returned nodes find the node whose `node["h"] == m.groups()[-1]`. So `parse_folder_url` would need to return `(root_folder, key, m.groups()[-1])`.