# Get files contained in a mega.nz folder with python 3.10

Tags: python

I need to retrieve the files contained in the MEGAsync folder of the Mega.nz service. I have been trying to do it for almost a week without success using the mega.py module. I have tried both with email and password, as well as with the public link of the folder. I have tried every example I found online (including those on Stack Overflow), but they all have thrown errors of various kinds. From non-existent methods to non-existent dictionary elements. It's as if the examples I found were from an old version of the module or something like that.

```
from mega import Mega
mega = Mega()
m = mega.login('example@example.com', 'example123')

# Get 'MEGAsync' folder
folder_name = 'MEGAsync'
folder = m.find(folder_name)

# Get the file list inside the folder
files = m.get_files_in_node(folder[0])

# Print file names on the list
for f in files:
    print(f['name'])
```

**Error:**

> print(f['name'])
> TypeError: string indices must be integers

In fact, in the dictionary 'files' obtained, it does not contain any names of the files contained in the MEGAsync folder

Can anyone give me the example of a code that really works?

Comment: What specifically is the problem with your code that doesn't *really* work?

Comment: If you get errors, [show the code you tried and the errors you got](/help/how-to-ask), otherwise people are just going to ask you try X, you respond with "I already tried that", repeat a dozen times. Give people the information they need in order to help you without needing a long comments conversation just to tease out the details.

Comment: Was this translation done by AI? FYI, [using them to generate content is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/4518341), but I'm pretty sure translation is fine. Anyway, if you're not confident in English, you might prefer asking on another language site: [es.so] / [pt.so] / [ru.so]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry for my language problems. My native language is Spanish. I have turned to Google translator to help me in the post.
I apologize for not knowing how to make me understand.
I have found something that partially solves my problem in:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488709/how-can-i-list-the-contents-of-a-mega-public-folder-by-its-shared-url-using-meg]
I appreciate your attention.